# Вложенный класс

Tags: python

Можно ли сделать вложенный приватный класс на Python?

```
class LList:
    class __Node:
        pass
    pass
```

Comment: Вложенный можно, а приватного в питоне ничего не бывает

Comment: Ну на уровне договоренности между питонистами, class __Node валидная запись или нет?

Comment: @RobertHovert Запускайте dir(LList). Там видно, что __Node даже именуется специально, так что "снаружи" доступ только хитрым образом.

Comment: @AlexTitov  _LList__Node?

Comment: @RobertHovert почитайте про двойное подчеркивание, оно для данных класса используется при устранения проблем с наследованием. Так что, верооятно, для обозначения приватности не является общепринятой идиомой.